# Login y Redireccion al index en Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

En anteriores aplicaciones que he realizado uno define un login y luego de logeado direcciones hacia la app algo como

localhost/ aqui carga contenido publico y un botón que diga iniciar sesión) que direcciona hacia 
localhost/login Una vez iniciada la sesión el direcciona hacia el dashboard
localhost/admin (Aqui solo se puede acceder con sesión abierta)

ahora con Laravel 5.7: el problema que estoy teniendo es que, necesito que una vez el usuario inicie sesión lo direccione hacia localhost/ se cargue el mismo contenido publico, pero en lugar de cargar el botón de iniciar sesión se muestre la información del usuario y un menú de cosas que el usuario una vez haya ingresado podría hacer

actualmente tengo definido un controlador llamado dashboard que se encarga de cargar el home.

sin embargo si le agrego

```
public function __construct(){
    $this->middleware('auth');
}
```

al controlador dashboard, al momento de cargar localhost/ el me direcciona al index

Answer (score 0):

Para ajustar la redirección después de iniciar sesión, utiliza la propiedad `$redirectTo` que encuentras en App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController:

```
/**
 * Where to redirect users after login.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $redirectTo = '/home';
```

Para mostrar un menú o similar en vez de un botón de ingreso en blade, tienes las directivas de autenticación @auth y @guest:

```
@guest
    // Usuario sin iniciar sesión
    // mostrar botón de ingreso
    <a href="#">Ingreso</a>
@else
    // Usuario que ya inició sesión
    // mostrar menú y etc.
    <ul>
      <li>Perfil</li>
      <li>Elemento de menú 2</li>
      <li>...</li>
    </ul>
@endguest
```